# Probability of rolling a pair of non-6's and a 6 on 3 dice

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

So the problem is asking for the probability of rolling 3 dice and getting a pair of non-6s and a 6. This is what I have so far:

Total possibilities $= 6^3=216$

Total possible pairs  $={(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)}=5$

Total ways to arrange a pair and a 6 $= 3$

So the total probability I got was $(5*3)/216=15/216=5/72$

My question is whether the total possible pairs is 5 or 10? I know that if you roll a 2 and a 3, it is considered a different arrangement than rolling a 3 then a 2. Does this concept apply at all if you're rolling a pair? Thank you!

Comment: So in the $6^3$ possibilities how many of them involve, say, $1,1,6$ in some order. I see only $116$, $161$, $611$. So the pair $(1,1)$ is counted once or twice?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you throw a red die and a blue die. If you get a 3 on the blue die and a 2 on the red die, that is different from getting a 2 on the blue die and a 3 on the red die.

If you get a 5 on the blue die and a 5 on the red die, is that different from getting a 5 on the blue die and a 5 on the red die?

The answer is no. There are only 5 pairs for you to consider, not 10.